# Provide params hash for put / post requests in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I find it more convenient to check response for some requests from within console

```
>> app.put '/users/2/'
=> 500
```

But wasn't able to find a way to specify request parameters. How I have to do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to put or post to a URL there are also methods for that. You can copy/paste the parameters exactly as they are displayed in your Rails production log:

```
app.post('/foo', {"this" => "that", "items" => ["bar", "baz"]})
app.put('/foo', {"this" => "that", "items" => ["bar", "baz"]})
```

If you want to sent a custom header, you can add an optional third parameter:

```
app.post('/foo', {:this => "that", :items => ["bar", "baz"]}, {"X-Do-Something" => "yes"})
```

Any of the get/post/put/delete methods will display their full log output on the console for you to examine. If you want to get information such as the response body returned, HTTP status or response headers these are easy too:

```
app.response.body

app.response.status

app.response.headers.inspect
```

Source: [http://andyjeffries.co.uk/articles/debug-level-logging-for-a-single-rails-production-request](https://web.archive.org/web/20130722234703/https://andyjeffries.co.uk/articles/debug-level-logging-for-a-single-rails-production-request/)

Answer (score 17):

The above has changed to

```
app.post '/foo', params: {"this" => "that", "items" => ["bar", "baz"]}
```

Also for forms I had to give an authenticity_token as well.
So in my example the full command was

```
app.post '/login', params: {email: 'my_email@gmail.com', password: 'abcd', authenticity_token: 'my_authenticity_token_generated_for_this_view' }
```